# MapStruct mapper based on type

Tags: java, mapstruct

Consider the following simplified structure (that has both a DO and a DTO for each):

```
Component {
   UUID id;
   String name;
}

MotherboardComponent extends Component {
    String type;
    List<Component> components;
}
```

For both I have a mapper that does the mapping between the DO and DTO, However, I am facing a problem and don't really know how to handle it. If for the `MotherboardComponent` in the list I have another `MotherboardComponent`, the resulting mapped object is to `ComponentDO` and not to `MotherboardComponentDO`.

How can I tell MapStruct to use the `MotherboardComponentMapper` inside the `MotherboardComponentMapper`, if the object is actually an extended one, not a base?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MapStruct does not do anything on runtime. It once knows about the types during compilation time.

In order to solve this problem you will have to help it a bit:

e.g.

```
@Mapper
public abstract class MotherboardComponentMapper {

    public abstract MotherboardComponentDO map(MotherboardComponent component);

    public ComponentDO map(Component component) {
        if (component instanceof MotherboardComponent) {
            return map((MotherboardComponent) component);
        }

        return mapAsComponentDO(component);
    }

    @Named("asComponentDO")
    protected abstract ComponentDO mapAsComponentDO(Component component);

}
```

Since we have marked the `mapAsComponentDO` with `@Named` MapStruct will not treat it is a possible method for mapping from `Component` to `ComponentDO` and it will use the `map(Component)` method instead.

There is an open issue for supporting such [down cast mapping](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/131) in the MapStruct issue tracker.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I will try this approach. At a first glance, it seems to be what I need.